# jnilib.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, visual-studio, dll

The fact is that I made my binder for games using the Java Native Interface, but apparently I did not compile the DLL correctly, since everything works fine for me (AMD64), and for a friend (Intel) it gives an UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find error dependent libraries. By the way, I'm using CMake to generate the dynamic library. My friend and I both have Windows 10 x64. Java 17 x64

Tree:

- binder.jar
- jnilib.dll

Code:

```java
public class InputManager {
    static {
        System.load(new File("KeyListenerJNI.dll").getAbsolutePath());
    }
    public static native void runManager();
}
```

I think it's because I didn't compile the DLL correctly. Can you tell me how can I compile DLL for other systems using Cmake & Visual Studio 17 2022

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Comment: Check *.dll* dependencies using 
[\[GitHub\]: lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies), or (older) [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com), or (*VStudio*'s) *DumpBin* ([\[MS.Docs\]: DUMPBIN Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference)) on both systems and see any difference.